# как сделать ограничение, на создание новых записей sql

Tags: sql

Допустим у меня есть таблицы Призеры, Спортсмены, Соревнования, как мне мне сделать, чтобы в таблице Призеры можно было создать **только** 3 записи каждого соревнования, то есть 3 колонки, id соревнования, id спортсмена и место

Comment: Думаю лучшим решением будет использование триггеров. Можно сделать триггер, чтобы перед вставкой новой записи в таблицу срабатывал триггер и подсчитывал кол-во записей, и если записей больше трех, то вызывается ошибка

Comment: Однако это решение подразумевает использование MySQL

Comment: Сделать enum с тремя значениями для места. Сделать эту колонку уникальной.

Comment: Сделать уникальный индекс  (id соревнования, id спортсмена, место). На колонку место ввести ограничение от 1 до 3. Правда, тогда можно несколько человек на одно место - ведь так бывает?

Comment: @ValNik А как именно, это что за команда? check?

Comment: Да, думаю надо использовать check. Пример (https://dbfiddle.uk/IOpwJB0s)

Comment: @ValNik так у меня же не размер занчения, а кол-во значений, если 3 уже есть места с один и тем же соревнованием, то не создавать запись

Comment: Согласен, нужен более жесткий случай. Уникальный индекс должен быть  (id соревнования, место) и место от 1 до 3. Т.е. допустимые записи (id соревнования1, место 1),(id соревнования1, место 2)(id соревнования1, место 3) Пример (https://dbfiddle.uk/OKPLhQHq) Правда, я здесь исхожу из того, что мест  всего 3.

Comment: Укажите используемую СУБД.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант ограничения числа записей предложу следующий вариант (SQL Server).

```
CREATE TABLE CheckTbl (col0 int,col1 int, col2 int);  
create unique index uIdx1 on CheckTbl (col0,col2);
ALTER TABLE CheckTbl  
ADD CONSTRAINT chkCol1ValueMin CHECK (col2 >= 1 );  

ALTER TABLE CheckTbl  
ADD CONSTRAINT chkCol1ValueMax CHECK (col2 <= 3 );
```

В примере col0 соответствует вашему Id соревнования, col1 - Id спортсмена, col2 - место. Создаем ограничение-уникальный индекс (col0,col2) и ограничения от 1 до 3 по величине col2.
Пробуем

```
insert into CheckTbl values (1,11,1);
insert into CheckTbl values (1,12,2);
insert into CheckTbl values (1,13,3);
insert into CheckTbl values (1,14,4);
insert into CheckTbl values (1,15,3);
insert into CheckTbl values (1,16,0);
Update CheckTbl set col2=5 where col0=1 and col1=13;
```

Первые 3 операции пройдут нормально.
Следующая вызовет ошибку

```
Msg 547 Level 16 State 0 Line 4
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chkCol1ValueMax".
The conflict occurred in database "fiddle_daf2dfcad6a1416bba8ba6f8669fff72",
 table "dbo.CheckTbl", column 'col2'.
```

Далее

```
Msg 2601 Level 14 State 1 Line 5
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.CheckTbl' with unique index 'uIdx1'.
The duplicate key value is (1, 3).
```

еще проверки

```
Msg 547 Level 16 State 0 Line 6
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chkCol1ValueMin".
The conflict occurred in database "fiddle_daf2dfcad6a1416bba8ba6f8669fff72",
 table "dbo.CheckTbl", column 'col2'.
Msg 547 Level 16 State 0 Line 7

The UPDATE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chkCol1ValueMax".
 The conflict occurred in database "fiddle_daf2dfcad6a1416bba8ba6f8669fff72",
 table "dbo.CheckTbl"
, column 'col2'.
```

[Пример здесь](https://dbfiddle.uk/0kmvHNsw)

Upd1. Если нужно ограничение безотносительно значений, думаю, придется применять триггер. Однако в stored proc или в приложении ловить ошибки из триггера очень не нравится.